# How do I share class members, safely?

Tags: c++

I'm struggling to organise a program. I have a class `Solver`, which looks like this:

```
class Solver {
   ...
   VarOrder order;
   ...
   vector<Constraint> watches;
   vector<Constraint> undos;
   ...
};
```

Where of course `Solver` uses these members to its business. However, `VarOrder` also needs to use `watches` and `undoes` to do *its* business and both classes need to be able to see each other's modifications. So it seems like I need to pass a pointer to the `watches` and `undoes` member variables into the constructor of `VarOrder`. I guess I should do that with `shared_ptr` to be safe, but pointers to vectors seems like opening a massive can of awful.

I could also use the "friends" feature of C++, but that seems wrong as well, since `VarOrder` only requires access to two of `Solver`'s members, not all of them, which seems like it would be weird design.

Probably my class design is wrong, but short of creating global data, I don't know how to reorganize this. Any advice appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to use shared pointers in this case, as those vectors have been allocated on the stack along with `VarOrder` and so they will all exist for the lifetime of each other.  Have `VarOrder` take a *reference* to the others (so no null pointer issues).

```
class VarOrder {
private:
    vector<Constraint>& _watches;
    vector<Constraint>& _undos;

public:
    VarOrder(vector<Constraint>& watches,
             vector<Constraint>& undos) : _watches(watches)
                                        , _undos(undos) {
    }; // eo ctor
}; // eo class VarOrder

class Solver {
private:
    vector<Constraint> _watches;
    vector<Constraint> _undos;
    VarOrder _order;

public:
    Solver() : _undos()
             , _watches()
             , _order(_watches, _undos) {
    }; // eo ctor
}; // eo class Solver
```

Note that members are initialised in the initialiser-list in the order in which they are **declared in the class**, so by the time _order comes around to construction, `_undos` and `_watches` are fully constructed.

Comment: This has a subtle bug: although you wrote the code in the right order in the constructor, the order in which the member constructors will be called is that of declaration. You will end up calling the constructor of order first, with two uninitialized vectors. It is not a big issue in this case but the code is brittle to change (e.g. if you want to check _watches.size() in the constructor of VarOrder). You should consider writing a setter for the values in VarOrder, or something similar.

Comment: @utnapistim, whoops!  well spotted.  Have amended.

Comment: +1 then. I deleted my answer as yours mentions all salient points.

Comment: @utnapistim, and they say chivalry is dead! :)

Comment: Thank you. Can't remember what I was doing now, but when I tried this references approach I was getting errors about not being able to have an uninitialized reference. Anyway, this works great! Will have to investigate what was going wrong earlier :)